# Iterating through all the <div> tags on a page

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, iteration

I want to go through all the  elements on a page using Javascript and see if they have a property set. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to use a recursive solution?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   //do something to each div like
   divs[i].innerHTML = "something new...";
}
```

Comment: It's best to use a standard "for" loop—"for in" loops are meant for iterating through objects.

Comment: Also, caching the array's length improves performance. For example: "for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; i++)"...

Comment: Can I just add that counting down from divs.length-1 to 0, rather than up, will be slightly faster, not noticeable most of the time, but it could come in handy to remember that at some point.

Comment: Where's does Sam Lee find the property he wants in this answer?

Answer (score 13):

To find a property in one or more of all divs on a page:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"), i=divs.length;
while (i--) {
   if (divs[i].getAttribute([yourProperty]) === 'yourValue'){
      //do something
   } 
}
```

[**edit october 2022**] Very old answer. Today I would advise to use a css selector. For example:

```js
const withStyle = document.querySelectorAll('[style]');
console.log(`Found ${withStyle.length} elements with style:\n${
  [...withStyle]
   .map(el =>`<${el.tagName}>: ${el.getAttribute('style')}`)
   .join(`; `) }` );
```

```html
<div style="color:#777">
  <div style="color:red;background:#EEE">red</div>
  <div>no color</div>
  <div data-something>data-attribute</div>
  <div style="color:green">green</div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <h3 style="font-family:monospace">That's all folks</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using JS `ES6` [`For ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
for (elem of document.getElementsByTagName('div')){
  elem.style.marginTop='20px'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also be able to use a selector engine such as [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

Steve

Comment: or jQuery

      $("div").each(function (i) {
        if (this.style.color != "blue") {
          this.style.color = "blue";
        } else {
          this.style.color = "";
        }
      });

Comment: I don't think your comment is related to my answer—it doesn't make use of any selectors. Why don't you post your jQuery code as another answer?