# Get text of the div that contains more than one characters

Tags: php, html, css, dom, simpledom

Imagine we want to get the **div,span,p,etc** of HTML page that the **class** OR **ID** name of that , contains some keywords like:

`one` & `two` & `three`

For example i have this HTML :

```
<div class="this_one">
  Need this !
</div>
<div id="some_three">
  Need this again !
</div>
<span id="two_this">
  Need again
</span>
<p class="NOT">
Not want this
</p>
```

I mean i want to get text inside of the special tags like (div,p,span) that the ID or CLASS of them , contains my words like (one,two,...)

How to detect them?

For example, with `simpledom` , or `PHPDOM`, or any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use PHP, then you can use `DOMDocument` + `DOMXpath`. I'm not a guru ath `xpath` but you could do something like:

```
$sample_markup = '<div class="this_one">
  Need this !
</div>
<div id="some_three">
  Need this again !
</div>
<span id="two_this">
  Need again
</span>
<p class="NOT">
Not want this
</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($sample_markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$search = $xpath->query('
    /html/body//*[
        contains(@class|@id, "one") or
        contains(@class|@id, "two") or
        contains(@class|@id, "three")
    ]
');

foreach($search as $node) {
    $value_inside_that_node = trim((string) $node->nodeValue);
    echo $value_inside_that_node . '<br/>';
}
```

Should output:

```
Need this !
Need this again !
Need again
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, you could do it using `[name*="value"]` selector, e.g. :

```
var patterns = ["one","two","three"];

var text = "";
for(i in patterns) {
    text += $("[id*='"+patterns[i]+"']").text();
    text += $("[class*='"+patterns[i]+"']").text();
 }

alert(text);
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/m3hjxgtc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over elements by their class using jquery selectors like this:

```
$("[class=className]").each(function( index ) {
   // do something here
});
```

To select multiple classes:

```
$("[class=className1], [class=className2]").each(function( index ) {
   // do something here
});
```

Here is JSFiddle example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFiddler/5Ltdmsz8/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JQuery's selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
// elements who's class contains one
$('[class~="one"]').click(function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to get all div,span or any other tag you want in a page. check content of each and if a match is found . use the name or id of the tag.

Something very similar is done on this link
[Iterating through all the <div> tags on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844869/iterating-through-all-the-div-tags-on-a-page)

Also go through

[Parse HTML div id include all inner contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886290/parse-html-div-id-include-all-inner-contents)

[PHP DOM parsing to get to elements inside specific div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823220/php-dom-parsing-to-get-to-elements-inside-specific-div-id)